# Connect to Oracle SQL in Katalon Studio

Tags: oracle, jdbc, groovy, katalon-studio

I tried to use Groovy script below from to connect to an `Oracle SQL` database:

```
def connectDB(String dataFile){
    //Load driver class for your specific database type
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
    String connectionString = "jdbc:sqlite:" + dataFile
    if(connection != null && !connection.isClosed()){
        connection.close()
    }
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString)
    return connection
}
```

There is sqlite in connection string, but not sure which value should I use there. (I tried `jdbc:oracle` too.)

I use following class to establish database connection.

```
public class sqlconnect {
    private static Connection connection = null;

    /**
     * Open and return a connection to database
     * @param dataFile absolute file path 
     * @return an instance of java.sql.Connection
     */
    @Keyword
    def connectDB(String dataFile){
        //Load driver class for your specific database type
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
        String connectionString = "jdbc:sqlite:" + dataFile
        if(connection != null && !connection.isClosed()){
            connection.close()
        }
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString)
        return connection
    }

    /**
     * execute a SQL query on database
     * @param queryString SQL query string
     * @return a reference to returned data collection, an instance of java.sql.ResultSet
     */
    @Keyword
    def executeQuery(String queryString) {
        Statement stm = connection.createStatement()
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(queryString)               
        return rs
    }

    @Keyword
    def closeDatabaseConnection() {
        if(connection != null && !connection.isClosed()){
            connection.close()
        }
        connection = null
    }

    /**
     * Execute non-query (usually INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/COUNT/SUM...) on database   
     * @param queryString a SQL statement
     * @return single value result of SQL statement
     */
    @Keyword
    def execute(String queryString) {
        Statement stm = connection.createStatement()
        boolean result = stm.execute(queryString)
        return result
    }
}
```

I already set database information under `Project > Settings > Database` in Katalon Studio.
I call from testcase with CustomKeyword `connectDB()` and `executeQuery()` methods.

**UPDATE:**

I updated `connectDB()` method `Groovy` script:

```
def connectDB(){
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
    //String connectionString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@ipaddress:port/servicename"
    if(connection != null && !connection.isClosed()){
        connection.close()
    }
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@ipaddress:port/servicename", "username", "password")
    return connection
}
```

I tried to use variable `connectionString` as a parameter of `DriverManager.getConnection()` method, but I got same error message in both cases.

> Cannot cast object 'oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@' with class
>   'oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection' to class
>   'com.mysql.jdbc.Connection'

Comment: The format of the connection string  is  `jdbc:oracle:<drivertype>:@<database>` (e.g. `jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:xe`). [Learn more about connection strings...](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html)

Comment: @JuanMellado : I fixed this string. I get `Connection succcesful!` message on GUI, but I get  `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied` error message when call `connectDB()` method.

Comment: You can pass the user and password on the call:  `DriverManager.getConnection
  ("<connection string>", "<user>", "<password>");`, or in the connection string: `jdbc:oracle:<drivertype>:<user>/<password>@<database>`

Comment: The problem in your latest edit just means you have imported `com.mysql.jdbc.Connection` (which is a MySQL class) instead of the JDBC interface `java.sql.Connection`. Fix your imports.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : Thanks, that is solved this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of the connection string is `jdbc:oracle:<drivertype>:@<database>` (e.g. `jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:xe`).

You can pass the user and password on the call: `DriverManager.getConnection("<connection string>", "<user>", "<password>");` or even in the connection string: `jdbc:oracle:<drivertype>:<user>/<password>@<database>` (e.g. `jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/tiger@host:1521:xe`).

You should learn [more about connection strings.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html)

Comment: I updated connection string, but got error message: `Cannot cast object 'oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@' with class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection' to class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Connection'` I use port number and service name to connect to database.

Comment: Have you tried calling `DriverManager.getConnection` with the user and password as parameters?

Comment: My `connectionString` named variable already conations username and password too. I used `connection = DriverManager.getConnection("<connection string>", "<user>", "<password>");` format, but got the same error message.

Comment: Please update your question with the current code you are using. You got a succcesful connection before, only username/password was wrong. But now you are reporting an error about "com.mysql.jdbc.Connection" (mysql?).

Comment: I updated it with modified connectDB() method. I call this from test case during execution.

Comment: Connection wasn't successful from code, only under Project > Settings > Database in Katalon Studio, by Test Connection button.