# unable to connect the MYSQL Server in katalon

Tags: java, groovy, katalon-studio

I tried to use Groovy script below from to connect to an SQL Server database:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
"databaseName=XXX;user=sa;password=XXXX;";
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

i have tried the above code but i am getting the exception as

> "'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection' to class
>   'com.mysql.jdbc.Connection'"

I use following class to establish database connection.

```
public class sqlconnect {
    private static Connection connection1 = null;

    @Keyword
    def connectDB(String server, String port, String dbname, String username, String password){
         String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + server + ":" + port + ";databaseName=" + dbname + ";user=" + username + ";password=" + password

        if(connection1 != null && !connection1.isClosed()){
            connection1.close()
        }
        connection1 = (java.sql.Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url)
        return connection1
    }


    @Keyword
    def executeQuery(String queryString) {
        Statement stm = connection1.createStatement()
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(queryString)
        return rs
    }

    @Keyword
    def closeDatabaseConnection() {
        if(connection1 != null && !connection1.isClosed()){
            connection1.close()
        }
        connection1 = null
    }


    @Keyword
    def execute(String queryString) {
        Statement stm = connection1.createStatement()
        boolean result = stm.execute(queryString)
        return result
    }
}
```

I already set database information under Project > Settings > Database in Katalon Studio. I call from testcase with CustomKeyword connectDB() and executeQuery() methods.

I tried to use variable connectionString as a parameter of DriverManager.getConnection() method, but I got same error message in both cases.

> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot
>   cast object 'ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId:
>   bc27bbec-c83e-4afe-a1bf-68c9091ae567' with class
>   'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection' to class
>   'com.mysql.jdbc.Connection'

Comment: can you also show the import statements of the class. Most likely you imported wrong class as Connection.

Comment: java.sql.connection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to Oracle SQL in Katalon Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237804/connect-to-oracle-sql-in-katalon-studio)

Comment: The error suggests you imported `com.mysql.jdbc.Connection` instead.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for the information i will check

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection
```

Don't use java.sql.Connection. Just Connection :]